# Problemas com algoritmo de aproximação de pi em C

Tags: c, algoritmo

Boa noite, estou com o seguinte problema, estou desenvolvendo um algoritmo para calcular uma aproximação de pi.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <locale.h>

int mmc(int num1, int num2) {

    int mmc, aux, c;
    if(num2==1)mmc=num1;
    else{
        for (c = 2; c <= num2; c++) {
            aux = num1 * c;
            if ((aux % num2) == 0) {
                mmc = aux;
                c= num2 + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return mmc;
}

double R1(int num){
    int cont=1;
    double pi=1.0, dAtual=1.0,dAnt,dCom=1.0,nume=1.0;
    for(;cont<=num;cont++){

        dAnt=dCom;
        dAtual=dAtual+2.0;
        dCom=mmc(dAtual,dAnt);
        if(cont%2==0) nume=nume*(dCom/dAnt)+(dCom/dAtual);
        else nume=nume*(dCom/dAnt)-(dCom/dAtual);
        pi=nume/dCom;


    }

    pi=pi*4;
    return pi;
}

double R2(int num){
    int cont=1;
    double pi=1.0, dAtual=1.0,dAnt,dCom=1.0,nume=1.0;
    for(;cont<=num;cont++){

        dAnt=dCom;
        dAtual=pow((cont+1.0),2);
        dCom=mmc(dAnt,dAtual);
        nume=nume*(dCom/dAnt)+(dCom/dAtual);
        pi=nume/dCom;


    }

    pi=sqrt((pi*6));

    return pi;
}

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");
    int n;

    printf("Digite um numero positivo: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);



    printf("\nA aproximação de pi com %d termos é:\n\n",n);
    printf("R1= %.15lf\n\n",R1(n));

    printf("R2= %.15lf\n\n",R2(n));

system("pause");
return (0);
}
```

O problema está na função R2, que a partir do 12ºtermo não consegue mais calcular e retorna -1,#IND0000, eu pensei que poderia ter ultrapassado o valor limite de double, e tentei mudar para long double, porém desse modo só retorna 0. Qual pode ser o problema?

A formula em que R2 foi baseada é essa:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#IND significa uma forma indeterminada.

O que você tem lá é conhecido como 'Não é um número' ou NaN para breve.

Citando a Wikipedia, a geração disso é feita por:

> - Operações com um NaN como pelo menos um operando.
> - As divisões 0/0 e ± ∞ / ± ∞
> - As multiplicações 0 × ± ∞ e ± ∞ × 0
> - As adições ∞ + (−∞), (−∞) + ∞ e subtrações equivalentes
> - A raiz quadrada de um número negativo.
> - O logaritmo de um número negativo
> - O seno inverso ou cosseno de um número menor que -1 ou maior que +1.

Você está fazendo pelo menos uma dessas coisas.

### Edit

Apenas complementando a resposta, com o código que o **Cleber** colocou, o problema era na função `mmc`.

O código ficaria assim:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <locale.h>

double R1(int n){
    int cont=2;
    double pi=1.0,i=3.0;
    if(n!=1){
        for(;cont<=n;cont++){

            if(cont%2==0) pi=pi-1.0/i;
            else pi=pi+1.0/i;
            i=i+2.0;

        }
    }

    return (pi*4.0);
}

double R2(int n){
    int cont=2;
    double pi=1.0,i=2.0;
    if(n!=1){
        for(;cont<=n;cont++){

            pi=pi+1.0/(i*i);
            i=i+1.0;

        }
    }

    return (sqrt(pi*6.0));
}

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");
    int n;

    printf("Digite um numero positivo: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);



    printf("\nA aproximação de pi com %d termos é:\n\n",n);
    printf("R1= %.15lf\n\n",R1(n));

    printf("R2= %.15lf\n\n",R2(n));

system("pause");
return (0);
}
```

Comment: Realmente, descobri agora que a função mmc me retorna em algum ponto um valor assim, troquei ela por uma simples multiplicação dAnt*dAtual em R2, porém no 98º termo ela para de funcionar novamente.

Comment: Não se esqueça de marcar como resolvida

Answer (score 0):

Consertei as duas funções R1 e R2 e descobri que a função mmc nesse caso era inútil, o problema era muito mais simples do que eu pensava. Segue o código de um jeito que funciona:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <locale.h>

double R1(int n){
    int cont=2;
    double pi=1.0,i=3.0;
    if(n!=1){
        for(;cont<=n;cont++){

            if(cont%2==0) pi=pi-1.0/i;
            else pi=pi+1.0/i;
            i=i+2.0;

        }
    }

    return (pi*4.0);
}

double R2(int n){
    int cont=2;
    double pi=1.0,i=2.0;
    if(n!=1){
        for(;cont<=n;cont++){

            pi=pi+1.0/(i*i);
            i=i+1.0;

        }
    }

    return (sqrt(pi*6.0));
}

int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Portuguese");
    int n;

    printf("Digite um numero positivo: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);



    printf("\nA aproximação de pi com %d termos é:\n\n",n);
    printf("R1= %.15lf\n\n",R1(n));

    printf("R2= %.15lf\n\n",R2(n));

system("pause");
return (0);
}
```